# Run few exec() commands one-by-one

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I need to run two shell commands, one-by-one. These commands are wrapped in to functions:

```
function myFucn1() {
     exec('some command',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                throw error;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        });
}
```

and

```
function myFucn2() {
     exec('some command 2',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                throw error;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        });
}
```

When I am calling them on my trigger function:

```
app.get('/my_end_point', (req, res) => {
    try {
        myFucn1();
        myFucn2();
        res.send('Hello World, from express');
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

it runs both commands in random order and output `stdout, stderr` displays only from second functions.

Comment: make myFucn1(); return something, and execute myFucn2 with an if.

Comment: Never Ever make your node behaviour synchronous. Always try to go natural way. Otherwise performance could be worst.

Comment: for the above purpose use websockets then you don't have to worry about request timeout. You can easily run async functions and get results at correct time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the commands don't execute in the same order everytime is because they get *launched* one after the other, but from then on JS doesn't control for how long they will be executed. So, for a program like yours that is basically this:

```
launch cmd1, then do callback1
launch cmd2, then do callback2
respond to the client
```

you don't have any control over when will `callback1` and `callback2` will get executed. According to your description, you are facing this one:

```
launch cmd1
launch cmd2
respond to the client
callback2
(something else happens in your program)
callback1
```

and that's why you only see what you see.

---

So, let's try to force their order of execution! You can use [`child_process`' `execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) but I wouldn't recommend it for production, because it makes your server program stays idle the whole time your child processes are executing.

However you can have a very similar syntax by using async/await and turning exec into an async function:

```js
const { exec: execWithCallback } = require('child_process');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(execWithCallback);

async function myFunc1() {
  try {
    const {stdout, stderr} = await exec('command 1');
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}

// same for myFunc2
```

and for your server:

```js
app.get('/my_end_point', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await myFunc1();
    await myFunc2();
    res.send('Hello World, from express');
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: `myFunc1` and `myFunc2` aren't depending on each other, so this solution is just not satisfying. The correct solution would be to promesify both the functions and then use `Promise.all`

Comment: So `await Promise.all(myFunc1(), myFunc2());`

Comment: @CristianTraìna that's only in the particular case where the commands don't need to be ran in order though

Answer (score 1):

You can use [execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) instead of *exec* to execute your commands synchronously.

```
const { execSync } = require("child_process");

function myFucn1() {
  return execSync("echo hello").toString();
}
function myFucn2() {
  return execSync("echo world").toString();
}

myFucn1();
myFucn2();
```

Comment: It's simple and it can work, but this is discouraged when trying to be performant, because it blocks the event loop the whole time the child process is executing

Comment: I agree and concede that your answer is better 

Answer (score 0):

It's due to nature of Javascript callback functions. Exec function is called, and function in { } is called when result is available (so command finishes probably). Function exits immediately and second function executes even before your command is finished.

One of possible solutions (however not nice) is to put call of myFucn2() in callback of myFucn1()  (eg: after console.error).

Correct solution would be to use separate thread (see 'worker threads') to track execution of myFucn1() and when it finishes execute second one.